# how to concatenate 2 strings or more in a loop in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, for-loop, spring-mvc

I have a problem concatenating two strings or more be one variable in a loop in java.

My expected result as below :

```
/AIP/FE/perindo/custrpt/res_cus_1744341512710002.xml,/AIP/FE/perindo/custrpt/res_cus_1744341512710003.xml
```

The result is saved in one variable and return the value like this:

```
/AIP/FE/perindo/custrpt/res_cus_1744341512710002.xml,/AIP/FE/perindo/custrpt/res_cus_1744341512710003.xml
```

The following that i implemented :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class pathData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
        
        String pthData = "\\\\10.28.88.28\\document\\FE\\perindo\\custrpt\\res_cus_1744341512710002.xml,\\\\10.28.88.28\\document\\FE\\perindo\\custrpt\\res_cus_1744341512710003.xml";
        String bk = splitPath(pthData);
        System.out.println(bk);
        
    }
    
    private static String splitPath(String bk) throws Exception {
        String[] Str = bk.split(",");
        String result = "";

        if(Str.length > 1) {
            for(int i = 0; i < Str.length; i++) {
                String[] ss = Str[i].split("\\\\");
                int a = ss.length;
                String as = "/AIP"+"/"+ss[a-4]+"/"+ss[a-3]+"/"+ss[a-2]+"/"+ss[a-1];
                
                result = as.concat(",");;
            }           
            return result;      
        }   
        return "";  
    }
}
```

Based on my code, the result is always returned a value like this

```
/AIP/FE/perindo/custrpt/res_cus_1744341512710003.xml,
```

please give instructions and correct where the error lies.

Comment: As per Javadocs **concat-** *Concatenates the specified string to the end of this string.* - so which String do you think it being concatenated to?  `=` is the assignment operator

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate not just a "," to "as" but also the value of "as" to result. Otherwise it will only contain the last assigned value.

Comment: Can you show me pls ? I can't imagine your explaination

Comment: Remove the part "result = " from the line "result = as.concat(",");" and in a following line write "result.concat(as);". That should do the work. Please tell me if it works.